# Error on Amazon aws EMR while running Mapreduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I am writing a map reduce code on my local cluster to Parse XML file. I am using jdom parser for that. It is working fine on my local cluster.

But when I am trying to create a job flow on EMR it is giving me following error :

" Error: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected "

I am using Hadoop 0.20.2 on my local machine. Please let me know if anyone knows what is the issue.

Here is the code for the record reader:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;


/**
   * Reads records that are delimited by a specifc begin/end tag.
 */
    public class XmlInputFormat extends  TextInputFormat {

public static final String START_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.start";
public static final String END_TAG_KEY = "xmlinput.end";

@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable,Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit is, TaskAttemptContext   
 tac)  {
    return new XmlRecordReader();
}
public static class XmlRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable,Text> {
    private  byte[] startTag;
    private  byte[] endTag;
    private  long start;
    private  long end;
    private  FSDataInputStream fsin;
    private  DataOutputBuffer buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
    private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
    private Text value = new Text();



    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit is, TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException, 
     InterruptedException {
        FileSplit fileSplit= (FileSplit) is;
        startTag = tac.getConfiguration().get(START_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");
        endTag = tac.getConfiguration().get(END_TAG_KEY).getBytes("utf-8");


        start = fileSplit.getStart();
        end = start + fileSplit.getLength();
        Path file = fileSplit.getPath();

        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(tac.getConfiguration());
        fsin = fs.open(fileSplit.getPath());
        fsin.seek(start);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (fsin.getPos() < end) {
            if (readUntilMatch(startTag, false)) {
                try {
                    buffer.write(startTag);
                    if (readUntilMatch(endTag, true)) {

                        value.set(buffer.getData(), 0, 
    buffer.getLength());
                        key.set(fsin.getPos());
                        return true;
                    }
                } finally {
                    buffer.reset();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return (fsin.getPos() - start) / (float) (end - start);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        fsin.close();
    }
    private boolean readUntilMatch(byte[] match, boolean withinBlock) throws IOException 
      {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            int b = fsin.read();
            // end of file:
            if (b == -1) return false;
            // save to buffer:
            if (withinBlock) buffer.write(b);

            // check if we're matching:
            if (b == match[i]) {
                i++;
                if (i >= match.length) return true;
            } else i = 0;
            // see if we've passed the stop point:
            if (!withinBlock && i == 0 && fsin.getPos() >= end) return false;
        }
     }

     }
       }
```

Comment: How do you create your job flow?

Comment: I create by following the procedure on Amazon Elastic Map Reduce. That is first create a job corresponding to a jar file and then specify the input and output from the s3 bucket. Then chose other parameters like number of instances to run and all. Finally run the job.

Comment: I meant can you detail exactly what command line you used to create your EMR jobflow? It's going to be hard to help you if we don't know what you even used.

Comment: If you go to amazon EMR console you will see an option to create job flow. If you select that option then you will be ask to choose the kind of job flow for your program. I selected custom jar and then did steps as mentioned in my previous comment. Have you used EMR before??

Comment: It would be good if you had specified you were running your EMR jobflow through the AWS console, there are many other ways to create an EMR jobflow and it wasn't clear from your message what you used. This is probably you using some old interface in your MapReduce job, but without more details about the exact code you're trying to run it will be hard to help you more.

Comment: I have added the XMLinput format that is record reader for the XML parsing in my original post above. Let me know if you need mapper and reducer code as well.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am facing similar problem. If yes then please update the ans